# NodeJS read JSON data with # in key

Tags: node.js, json, handlebars.js

I have the following structure of JSON:

```
{
  '#type': 'select',
  '#options':
   { '0': 'cocaine',
     '1': 'heronie',
     '2': 'opiods',
     '3': '[amphetamines]',
     '4': 'ecstasy' 
   },
   '#correct': 'testing_correct_for select' 
}
```

How can I read the primary key values, i:e the ones starting with a #?

I tried the following approach but output is declared as undefined.

```
        console.log(data.options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.

For you case - property name include special characters, you have to use `object['property']` expression, like:

`console.log(data['#options']);`

Comment: Thanks. Turned out to indeed being that simple